# how to select sibling element when click a link?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have serval link buttons in order to show a div below it.

```
<a class="btnComment" onclick="showComment()" isshow='0'>{{ post_comments.count }} comment</a>
<div class="comment">
....
</div>
<a class="btnComment" onclick="showComment()" isshow='0'>{{ post_comments.count }} comment</a>
<div class="comment">
....
</div>
<a class="btnComment" onclick="showComment()" isshow='0'>{{ post_comments.count }} comment</a>
<div class="comment">
....
</div>
```

I want to clink one linkbutton and only show the div element below it. but my js code:

```
function showComment(){
                   var isshow=$(this).attr('isshow');
                   if(isshow=="0"){
                       this.$(".comment").show();
                       $(this).attr('isshow',"1");
                   }
                   else{
                       this.$(".comment").hide();
                       $(this).attr("isshow","0");
                   }
               }
```

this show all div. and when i use $(this).siblings() or $(this).next(), i got null, i don't know why that not work.

What can i do?

Comment: Please upload your code to http://www.jsFiddle.net

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this` is not pointing to the element if you run it in an inline event. Try the following:

```
onclick="showComment(this)"
```

And:

```
           function showComment(el) {
               var isshow=$(el).attr('isshow');
               if(isshow=="0"){
                   $(el).next(".comment").show();
                   $(el).attr('isshow',"1");
               }
               else{
                   $(el).next(".comment").hide();
                   $(el).attr("isshow","0");
               }
           }
```

Or if you use jQuery's `click`, you can use `this` to point to the element:

```
$('.btnComment').click(function(event) {
    var isshow=$(this).attr('isshow');
    if(isshow=="0"){
        $(this).next(".comment").show();
        $(this).attr('isshow',"1");
    }
    else{
        $(this).next(".comment").hide();
        $(this).attr("isshow","0");
    }
});
```

Comment: Or he can simply use event.target

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your `<a>` and `<div>` inside another `<div>` to create a more maintainable code. Like this:

```
<div class="commentContainer">
  <a class="btnComment" isshow='0'>{{ post_comments.count }} comment</a>
  <div class="comment">
  ....
  </div>
<div>
```

This parent div serves as the ***context*** for your tags. In the future, if you change the position, move `<a>` after `<div>`, your code still works fine. And it's even possible for you to to styling as a group just by assigning a class to the container.
Your jquery, here I use jquery event handler instead.

```
$(".btnComment").click(function () {
    var isshow = $(this).attr('isshow');
    var parent = $(this).closest(".commentContainer");
    if (isshow == "0") {
        parent.find(".comment").show();
        $(this).attr('isshow', "1");
    } else {
        parent.find(".comment").hide();
        $(this).attr("isshow", "0");
    }
}
```

If you use `.next()`, it means your code is coupled to the current html.

Comment: That's exactly what we have element.siblings("div") for

Comment: @Itay: what if in the future, we have more levels deep?

Comment: @Itay: the idea here is to create a container for each group, so they are separate from each other.

Comment: What if the common parent for these items will be two elements above and not only one? If we'll play 'what if's too much, it wouldn't end

Comment: @Itay: you see the meaning of `.commentContainer`. What we care about is the class.

Comment: Did you mean using [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) ? Because you've wrote `nearest()`

Comment: @Itay: Imagine when you design something like a reusable comment control on server side. Do you think we should create a container (context) for all our stuff inside (from OOP point of view)?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35687/discussion-between-itay-and-khanh-to)

Answer (score 0):

css

> .hide{visibility:hidden;}
>       .show{visibility:visible;}

jquery

> $('.btnComment').click(function(){
>       $('.btnComment + div').removeClass('show').addClass('hide'); 
>       $(this).next().removeClass('hide').addClass('show');   });

html

> <a class="btnComment" href="javascript:;"
>   sshow='0'>click1</a>
>  < div
>   class="hide">sandy1</div>
>  <a class="btnComment"
>   href="javascript:;" isshow='0'>click2</a>
>  <div
>   class="hide">sandy2</div>
>  <a class="btnComment"
>   href="javascript:;" isshow='0'>click3</a>
>  <div
>   class="hide">sandy3</div>

On every click of anchor tag respective div will be shown and others will be hidden. 
Hope this will help you.